# Need detailed working or explanation of SCAN register in DSPIC

Tags: pic, adc

I am not able to figure out the working of SCAN register in DSPIC30F2010.I need to read 4 analog inputs in ADC and for that need to set the sampling and conversion

Comment: There is no SCAN register, but there is ADCSSL. What is unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [**dsPIC30F2010 datasheet**](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70118J.pdf),

> The inputs are selected by the ADCSSL register. If a particular bit in
>   the  ADCSSL register is ‘1’, the corresponding input is selected. The
>   inputs are always scanned from lower to higher numbered inputs,
>   starting after each interrupt. If the number of inputs selected is
>   greater than the number of samples taken per interrupt, the higher
>   numbered inputs are unused.

[**Code example is here**](http://www.electronics-base.com/dspic-tutorial/dspic-a-d-converter/dspic30f-analog-to-digital-converter-adc-example) (for 4013, but the idea is the same)

Comment: in which application,do we need this?

Comment: it is sufficient to use only the MUXA by setting bits in ADCHS, then why there are extra registers to scan it